# Django-mptt registration for an existing model

Tags: django, django-mptt, mptt

I tried to apply mptt in my django program on a existing model using the method provided on the main site of mptt, which is as follow:

```
import mptt
from mptt.fields import TreeForeignKey
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

# add a parent foreign key
TreeForeignKey(Group, blank=True, null=True, db_index=True).contribute_to_class(Group,'self')

mptt.register(Group, order_insertion_by=['name'])
```

However, when I open my group list in the admin-site, it says that the group model doesn't have such column named parent_id, I wonder how I can fix it.

BTW the code have been written in models.py,is it possible that I should have written it in admin.py?

reference: [Registration of existing models](http://django-mptt.github.io/django-mptt/models.html#registration-of-existing-models)

#### Edit:

sorry about the comment...migrations does solve the problem ><
However it leads to another question...can I only create a group by code to create a new tree structure, or it's possible for me to do that somewhere in my admin site?
Thanks for the answering and attention:)

Comment: nah...migrations doesn't really solve it. Django tells me that there are no migrations to make.